# Python 3.7 - Fails import sharepy

Tags: python-3.x

I have just started using Python for work & I am fairly new to Python.

I have tried to connect to SharePoint Online 2013 and found [sharepy](https://pypi.org/project/sharepy/) which seems to do what I need it to do

However when I run 'import sharepy' I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Python Programs/Tests/ConnectionToSharePoint/TheConnectionToSharePoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sharepy
  File "...\Python Programs\Tests\ConnectionToSharePoint\venv\lib\site-packages\sharepy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .session import SharePointSession
  File "...\Python Programs\Tests\ConnectionToSharePoint\venv\lib\site-packages\sharepy\session.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pip install requests` or `pip3 install requests` if you have both python 2.x and 3.x installed and you are working with python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

It seems sharepy depends on a basic python module called ['requests'](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

install it using pip install and it will probably do the trick